# How to name the thing that has components?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the best name for the abstract thing which contains components?

Context: I am writing an abstraction in a computer program. My domain consists of abstract `entities`. I don't know what concrete entities will exist later on. But I know, some entities are `components` of other entities.

An example concretization of the abstraction would be the entities `house`, `window` and `door`. Here `window` and `door` are components of a `house`. So the `house` is the `???` of `windows` and `doors`?

The word will be used in source code and also on the user interface. In questions or in error messages:

- Is a house a `???` of a window?
- What is a house the `???` of?
- What is the `???` of a window?
- Error: A door is not a `???` of a window.

Note that the word must work in unknown domains. Instead of `house`, `window` and `door`. It could be `body`, `arm` and `finger`. Or `continent`, `country` and `city`.

The user will be building a tree of entities of his own choice. The software needs to name them as `entities`, `components` and `???`.

An `entity` could be a `component` and a `???` at the same time.

A compound word would be ok, but the shorter, the better.

What I have ruled out:

- `collection` - because usualy a collection has items of the same type. and collection is already used in the core of my programming language and this would create a name collision.

What I am considering:

- `container`
- `composition`

Comment: What words have you ruled out? I assume that you've eliminated "container" as an option.

Comment: Formally, a *component* is one of many items which *compose* a *composition*; but that's not likely to be very useful for the ordinary user. Why not use the simple terms *whole* and *part*? -- "Is a house the whole of which a window is part?"

Comment: I like `container`. The word `component` is already set, so `whole` is not that good.

Comment: Doors can have windows, no?

Comment: If doors could have windows, then doors would be ’???’ of windows.

Comment: I'd suggest 'parent', in a coding context.

Comment: It would be odd to say that a house is a container for its doors, windows, etc. If one were to characterise a house as a container, one would probably be thinking of it as a container for, say, furniture, i.e. for things that are within it, but **distinct** from it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this type of naming question is specifically excluded in the help center. See: https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 5):

You could try

> assembly

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/assembly) says:

> a: the fitting together of manufactured parts into a complete
> machine, structure, or unit of a machine
>
> **b: a collection of parts so assembled**

Answer (score 4):

I'd go with **parent** in this case. The *parent* has several *child* components. A "parent-child relationship" is a pretty common phrase in computer science, and it would seem to fit most of your examples:

- Is a house a *parent* of a window?
- What is a house the *parent* of?
- What is the *parent* of a window?
- Error: A door is not a *parent* of a window.

Answer (score 1):

I will go out on a limb and say that "vessel" can be used to fit your requirements, or at least people will understand it clearly enough, and saying 'A house is a vessel of a window' sounds cool enough.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/vessel

vessel

container; water craft; airship:

vessel (ˈvɛsəl)

n
1. any object used as a container, esp for a liquid

Notice the linked dictionary doesn't contain spaceship, but Chekov used it as such anyways.

Comment: Neither *vessel* nor *container* (suggested above) can do the job, because things contained in a vessel/container are **not** its components. Wine contained in a bottle is not a component of the bottle.

Comment: @jsw29 container is not ruled out, the question says so itself, so thus neither is vessel.

Comment: @jsw29 and since a vessel can also mean a craft, which have doors and windows and such, it's easy to use it in a way like the example I give. Not to mention a container can have a door and a window. Or are you arguing that a person in the house is not part of the house so the OP's example itself is wrong because it can contain things that are not its components?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the word [**corpus**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/corpus) to describe something made up of smaller components.

A corpus is the body of the whole which is then comprised of smaller units.  It's used in literature to describe an entire body of works.  It also refers to a collection of pieces of knowledge on a subject.

The term originated from anatomy, meaning the body.  Bodies are composed of limbs and organs, and you can argue that these serve the same function as your program components.

---

Also, given that we're discussing computer programming, there already exists a term for this sort of thing:

**Program**.  For example: Microsoft Word is a series of components and subroutines brought together into one program.

A collection of programs is usually called a **suite**.  For example: Microsoft Office.

You may wish to stick to these existing conventions.

Answer (score 1):

Two terms probably worthy of consideration are "aggregation" and "compound".

References:

```
From The Free On-line Dictionary of Computing (18 March 2015) [foldoc]:

aggregation

 <programming> A composition technique for building a new
 {object} from one or more existing objects that support some
 or all of the new object's required interfaces.

 (1996-01-07)


Compound \Com"pound\, a. [OE. compouned, p. p. of compounen. See
 {Compound}, v. t.]
 Composed of two or more elements, ingredients, parts;
 produced by the union of several ingredients, parts, or
 things; composite; as, a compound word.
 [1913 Webster]
```

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft uses the word collection. ICollection is a base class of List<> And Dictionary<> among others. Typically a Collection contains homogeneous items. At least all using a common base class.

Your house could contain “Feature” base class object that are subclassed into “Window” and “Door”

Your house could also contain multiple properties that are themselves collections. House.Windows[4] and House.Doors[3]. If this is the case for your code, then house is not a collection.  It is a class or object with properties.

Aside, for visual elements Microsoft uses the word Container.

At least if you follow Microsoft’s recommendation you will use a language common to many developers and that has value.

Comment: Good answer. It makes the point I was making at the end of my answer. Use existing terminology from the CS world. +1.

Comment: I think `collection` is misleading, because it already has a very specific meaning in the programming language. And it is different from what I am looking for - it si for items of the same type.